Font rendering issue in c++ applcation on WSL with Qt6
I'm developing a C++ application using Qt6 on WSL, using Ubuntu 22.04. This application prints braille characters to the screen when when clicking and dragging in the canvas. The problem is the following:
if i run the app directly or using this script:
#!/bin/bash
./braille-drawer &
it works properly and the braille characters get properly rendered:

But if I run the app either through this shell script:
#!/bin/bash
SCRIPT_DIR="$(dirname "$(realpath "$0")")"
PROGRAM_PATH="$SCRIPT_DIR/braille-drawer"
"$PROGRAM_PATH" &
Or through neovim, using DAP to open the app in debugging mode, the braille characters don't get properly rendered, instead showing as hollow big squares, and some properties that I read from the braille characters, such as the width, which I use for the cell size, also change. here is the code for that:
void BrailleCanvas::updateGrid(){
    brailleFont = QFont("DejaVu Sans Mono", fontSize);
    QFontMetrics fm(brailleFont);
    tileWidth = fm.horizontalAdvance("⣿");

The value of tileWidth changes depending if the program is correctly run and the braille characters are properly detected, or not. This is also what affects that the size of a grid tile in the following image is different than the image from before:

I first got the problem when debugging in neovim using nvim-dap, so I thought the problem was there. Later I tried with the shell scripts provided above, and even though they are very similar scripts, one works properly and the other not, so I don't really know what's the problem.

I don't understand how useful displaying Braille on a display is.  My understanding is that Braille needs to be touched to read.

The Braille is used as a visual representation for drawing purposes, similar to using ASCII characters for art. The intention is not for reading it.

Unicode  (U+1145B) Newa Placeholder Mark aka "square character" is a placeholder for unsupported or missing character. Either chosen font doesn't contain required character (they never can contain all of over two million of letters), or locale difference had broken it

@LeoBoeri If you get squares, it means that the font doesn't support that character, and there's no guarantee that a font contains all the unicode blocks, including Braille Patterns. Besides, it seems a bit pointless (no pun intended) to use a character from an optional utf block just to draw 6 points. Wouldn't it be simpler to just use custom painting, or even a pixmap?
